# UIWebview freezes when browsing?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I'm facing some problems when browsing trough our webshop using an `UIWebview`. It just freezes the entire app until loaded (which can take up to 15 seconds). After fast clicking to other categories my app stops responding to touches, but it seems memory and CPU stay stable (30-40mb and CPU stays very low).

I'm using multiple `UIWebviews` within a `UITabbar` controller. Anyone an idea what causes this problem? I seem to find multiple questions related to mine, but none solutions given which will also work for me.

Comment: Every answer on the site? Sure, that won't be a good idea. Impossible. Though, for the edits I did, please read the meta before telling me they are useless. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89592/implement-e-g-language-lang-css-in-preview

Comment: At such a rate, nothing seems impossible. These tags intended to improve the site usability, not spoil it. While bumbing questions in hundreds makes it worse.

Comment: @JoranDenHouting so you are basing your edits that add nothing but code tags on a 2 year old question in which a developer said in an answer that this was fixed in the next build in June of 2011?

Comment: Please also note that your edits need at least 3 other people to review them. Just wait until you get to 2k if you really feel the edits are needed; then it's just your time, not the time of 3 others too. (Your edits are discussed [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203689/serial-pointless-editing).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same problem and found out it was caused by an Ajax script on my webpage which took to long. The UIWebview is not a great thing to use, but when the pages are stable, use not to many javascripts, it should work without facing high CPU.

So, take a look at your page, look at the javascript/ajax/jquery and let me know the result!

Comment: It's been a while I made this question, but indeed we found out about an AJAX call that was too big on that page. We where getting all the product information for the category, but the specific categorie contained 2000+ products. We already fixed it, thanks for you answer though as your answer actually contains the problem we faced. Will accept it :)

Comment: Hello, user2819389 i'm not using any of these javascript/ajax/jquery even web view freezing any help ?